# How to submit a form to an ASP.Net Core API Controller

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

I'm developing an Angular 2 application with ASP.Net Core 2.0 and C#.

I'm new in Angular 2 and I've been reading [Angular - Forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms) documentation and searching but I haven't found how to send a form to an ASP.Net Api.

Now, my problem is how to get the form data and send it using `http.post`.

`Html` code:

```
<h1>L&iacute;neas</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>

<p *ngIf="!lines"><em>Loading...</em></p>
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #lineForm="ngForm">
    <table class='table' *ngIf="lines">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Line Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Line Reference Id</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let line of lines">
                <td>{{ line.lineId }}</td>
                <td><input [(ngModel)]="line.name" placeholder="name" required name="name-{{line.lineId}}"></td>
                <td><input [(ngModel)]="line.lineReferenceId" placeholder="lineReferenceId" name="lineReferenceId-{{line.lineId}}" required></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

`TypeScript` code:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'line',
    templateUrl: './line.component.html'
})
export class LineComponent {
    public lines: Line[];
    private baseUrl: string;
    private http: Http;

    constructor(http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        this.http = http;
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;

        http.get(baseUrl + 'api/Line').subscribe(result => {
            this.lines = result.json() as Line[];
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }

    onsubmit() {
        this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/Line/Save', JSON.stringify(this.data))
            .subscribe(result => { }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}

interface Line {
    lineId: number;
    name: string;
    lineReferenceId: string;
}
```

My problem is here: `this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/Line/Save', JSON.stringify(this.data))`. I don't know how to get form data: `this.data` doesn't exist.

How can I get the form?

By the way, I don't know if this is the right way to get base url and http client in the constructor:

```
this.http = http;
this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is bound to the variable 'lines'. So try the following:

```
onsubmit() {
    this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/Line/Save', JSON.stringify({ lines: lines }))
        .subscribe(result => { }, error => console.error(error));
}
```

Then on your backend find the post key 'lines'.
Your code to get http class and url strings are fine.