# ASP.NET Core and Angular : invalid operation error on submitting form

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, angular10, angular12

I have a form created in Angular 12 and ASP.NET Core Web API.

Here is controller portion:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<ModelClassView>> AddRecord(ModelClass objModelClass)
{
            _context.VisitorChildreRequest.Add(objModelClass);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

.......................
.............
}
```

Here is sample html:

```
<!--html-->
<form  #frmPersonalDetails="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmitIndividualDetails(frmPersonalDetails)">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label> NAME</label>
    <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Full Name" name="CHILDERN_FULLNAME" #CHILDERN_FULLNAME="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.CHILDERN_FULLNAME" >
  </div>
  <div>
         <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" [disabled]="frmPersonalDetails.invalid">Submit form</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is the component:

```
//component
onSubmitIndividualDetails(form: NgForm) {
this.service.AddSubscription(form);
}
```

And my service:

//service

```
const customHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
customHeaders.set('content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8;');
readonly url = 'http://localhost:43186/ControllerName/AddRecord';

AddSubscription(form: NgForm) {
  return this.http.post<any>(url, form.value, { headers: customHeaders });
}
```

Output :
On debugging asp.net core controller shows this exception

```
> Request.query, querystring all is null  
> Request.Form shows 'Invalid operation exception'
```

Although service class shows data in json format submitted via form and component.

On submitting form it hits the web api but does not show anything in Request object.

What is the reason that the ASP.NET Core controller not able to fetch any values submitted from the Angular form?

Comment: Can [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644358/how-to-submit-a-form-to-an-asp-net-core-api-controller) help you?

Comment: It shows data on component and service level, but WebApi shows null values of Model class.